# How to change background opacity (alpha) of an element when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll, alpha

I have a transparent navigation bar that I would like to smoothly fade into the background color as the user begins to scroll down the page.

Then return to fully transparent when the user scrolls back to the top of the page.

I am a graphic designer, and my proficiency with JavaScript is, admittedly, quite weak.

I would like to achieve a similar effect to what is being done with color in the code snippet below, but I only need the alpha channel to change (I don't see where this is possible with this section of code).

```js
const [red, green, blue] = [69, 111, 225]
const section1 = document.querySelector('.section1')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / 150
  const [r, g, b] = [red / y, green / y, blue / y].map(Math.round)
  section1.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
})
```

```css
.section1 {
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: rgb(69, 111, 225)
}
```

```html
<div class="section1"></div>
```

[CodePen for a similar effect](https://codepen.io/atomiks/pen/dgMNwG)

MY CURRENT CODE:

```
        <!--      Main Nav      -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-  toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="fas fa-bars" id="hamburgerMenu"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item top-nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">My Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1"      aria-disabled="true">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--/      Main Nav      -->
```

```
    .navbar {
    background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, 0);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 1.25s ease-out;
    transition: background-color 1.25s ease-out;
}

.navbar:hover,
.navbar:focus {
    background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, .9) !important;
}

.navbar:active,
.navbar:visited {
    background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, 0) !important;
}

@keyframes navbar-fadein {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, .98);
    }
}

@keyframes navbar-fadein {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, .9);
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgba(247, 252, 255, 0.7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either use RGBA or set opacity from the callback.

Comment: Changing the background opacity of an element and changing opacity of the entire element are two different things. Which one do you want?

Comment: Hi amn, I am wanting to change the background-color opacity on scroll; I'll edit my post to include a snippet of my code (I'm currently removing transparency on hover, but would like to also remove it when the user scrolls down and restore it when they scroll back to the top)